# Intervene A Long Running Thread With contextDestroyed

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I need to show some code to explain my problem.

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ServletContextAttribListener implements ServletContextListener
{
private ServletContext context = null;
private MyThread myThread = new MyThread(true);

// This method is invoked when the Web Application
// is ready to service requests

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    this.context = event.getServletContext();
    // Output a simple message to the server's console
    myThread.start();
    System.out.println("The Simple Web App. Is Ready");
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)
{
    // Output a simple message to the server's console
    System.out.println("The Simple Web App. Has Been Removed");
    myThread.setB(false);
    this.context = null;
}

public class MyThread extends Thread
{
    private boolean b;

    public MyThread(boolean b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (b)
        {
            //This part is important
            for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
            {
            }
            //
            j++;
        }
        System.out.println("Thread stopped i:->" + i + " j:->" + j);
    }

    public boolean isB()
    {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(boolean b)
    {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see it is very small and dummy program. I didn't write web.xml, I'm just using listener-class.
When I deploy the war, start and stop tomcat, the output of the program is:

```
The Simple Web App. Is Ready
The Simple Web App. Has Been Removed
Thread stopped i:->1000000 j:->17296
```

As you can see i is 1000000 as in the for loop. What I want is to break the loop whether i is 1000000 or smaller than that.

You can say that I can use **b** condition with **i<1000000** in for loop but in my real program I don't have that for loop. I just have a while loop like here but with numerous lines of code within it. I don't want to check **b** every time within while.

I can't use sleep/interrupt by the way.

Comment: How long does the "numerous lines of code" take to execute? A second? A minute? An hour ?

Comment: It might take maximum 5 or 6 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clean way to stop a thread without this thread's collaboration. So, if you need to stop as soon as possible, you'll have to check the stop flag (`b` in your example) as often as possible.

BTW, the `b` flag should be `volatile`, else your thread might never stop.

Comment: Yea your are right about volatile point. If you say so about thread life cycle, then I need to check b in while loop a lot of times.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to join with the thread when the context gets destroyed.